# Defferred result in empty JSP page empty page loading (Spring MVC 3.2.3.RELEASE + tomcat 7)

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat7, deferred-rendering

hi I'm writing a webapplication using servelet-api 3.0.1 with the async request processing.

Basically I use spring mvc controller, and Request mapping where I return an ModelAndView as deffered result.

My controller looks as follows

```
@RequestMapping("/deferred-result/model-and-view")
    public DeferredResult<ModelAndView> deferredResultWithView() {
        final DeferredResult<ModelAndView> result = new DeferredResult<ModelAndView>();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Hello world");
                result.setResult(new ModelAndView("views/html", "javaBean", new JavaBean("bar", "apple")));
            }
        }).start();
        return result;
    }
```

My JSP looks as follows

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My HTML View</title>
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/form.css" />" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />     
</head>
<body>
<div class="success">
    <h3>foo: "${javaBean.foo}"</h3>
    <h3>fruit: "${javaBean.fruit}"</h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have narrow down the problem as follows,
when I return ModelAndView synchronously (that means without DefferedResult) Jsp content is loading perfectly as I expected.

I'm getting following log in my tomcat log. And the content of the page is not loading. Instead I'm getting an empty page.

> Sep 29, 2013 3:09:03 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache
>   tldScanJar INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained
>   no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of
>   JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping
>   unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP
>   compilation time.